# Connect Android Studio with Google Colab code

Tags: python, android, machine-learning

I am making a android app to recognize songs in android studio. The ML code for recognition is on google colab, so how can I use the code in android studio. Is there a way for real time communication between android studio and google colab. Or is there any other way to use the python code inside android studio.

Comment: Is there information about Colab anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can surely use it.
Coming to basics you can always have a server and access it across all your clients.
Newer trends focus on edge computing.

1. Freeze your model, make a flask API wrapper, and host it and access your model in-app via API's.
2. For testing purposes, you can run flask code in colab itself and tunnel it using ngrok. check https://pypi.org/project/pyngrok/
3. You can freeze model to TFlite and use it in app via JAVA code, research on it. see [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide)